# How do I create a list of all possible anagrams of a word/string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, anagram

How do I create a list of all possible anagrams of a word/string in **PostgreSQL**.

For example if String is '**act**'
then the desired output should be:

**act,
atc,
cta,
cat,
tac,
tca**

I have one Table 'tbl_words' which contains million of words.

Then I want to check/search for only valid words in my database table from this anagrams list.

Like from above list of anagrams valid words are : **act, cat**.

Is there any way to do this?

**Update 1:**

I need output like this:
(all permutation for given word  )

[image]

any idea ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL combinations without repetitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111515/postgresql-combinations-without-repetitions)

Answer (score 2):

The query generates all permutations of 3 elements set:

```
with recursive numbers as (
    select generate_series(1, 3) as i
),
rec as (
    select i, array[i] as p
    from numbers
union all
    select n.i, p || n.i
    from numbers n
    join rec on cardinality(p) < 3 and not n.i = any(p)
)
select p as permutation
from rec
where cardinality(p) = 3
order by 1

 permutation 
-------------
 {1,2,3}
 {1,3,2}
 {2,1,3}
 {2,3,1}
 {3,1,2}
 {3,2,1}
(6 rows)
```

Modify the final query to generate permutations of the letters of a given word:

```
with recursive numbers as (
    select generate_series(1, 3) as i
),
rec as (
    select i, array[i] as p
    from numbers
union all
    select n.i, p || n.i
    from numbers n
    join rec on cardinality(p) < 3 and not n.i = any(p)
)
select a[p[1]] || a[p[2]] || a[p[3]] as result
from rec
cross join regexp_split_to_array('act', '') as a
where cardinality(p) = 3
order by 1

 result 
--------
 act
 atc
 cat
 cta
 tac
 tca
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
with recursive params as (
      select *
      from (values ('cata')) v(str)
     ),
     nums as (
      select str, 1 as n
      from params
      union all
      select str, 1 + n
      from nums
      where n < length(str)
     ),
     pos as (
      select str, array[n] as poses, array_remove(array_agg(n) over (partition by str), n) as rests, 1 as lev
      from nums
      union all
      select pos.str, array_append(pos.poses, nums.n), array_remove(rests, nums.n), lev + 1
      from pos join
           nums
           on pos.str = nums.str and array_position(pos.rests, nums.n) > 0
      where cardinality(rests) > 0
     )
select distinct pos.str , string_agg(substr(pos.str, thepos, 1), '')
from pos cross join lateral
     unnest(pos.poses) thepos
where cardinality(rests) = 0 
group by pos.str, pos.poses;
```

This is quite tricky, particularly when there are repeated letters in the string.  The approach taken here generates all permutations of the numbers from 1 to n, where n is the length of the string.  It then uses these as indexes to extract characters from the original string.

Those who are keen will notice that this uses `select distinct` with `group by`.  That seems like the easiest way to avoid duplication in the resultant strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it works fine.  i have few queries i need to select this result in @temp table and then write some logic which search this list of anagram in tbl_words and will return only valid words.